# Strange thing happned Windows XP switched to Windows 7 programs

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

I had Windows 7 installed in one drive. Then I installed Windows XP on the other drive.
I was installing the software and everything was working fine on my desktop PC.

Suddenly my resolution changed and what I see the desktop and programs which were installed on Windows 7. The Windows is XP but all programs automatically changed to which were installed on Windows 7

EDIT: When I installed XP then I was installed all software in it. While everything was ok, I was installing WinRar. Then suddenly screen got blackout. Then when screen came back after 5 seconds. Then I lost my graphics card driver. All icon become big and I saw that all icons on my desktop was from Windows 7 desktop. I checked my program list and all programs were from Windows 7 which I installed in Windows 7. I don't know how got swapped.

Comment: Could you have a go at rephrasing the second paragraph, it is hard to follow what exactly happened.

Comment: ^ agree, it sounds like mabey the XP is lapped on top of the windows 7 instalation? (and not on the intended other drive)

Comment: they are on separate partitions